Attempt to read property "image" on null Laravel 11
I have a method that transfers related data from the model UserList to the template
public function show(User $user, UserLists $list): View
{
    $elements = $list->elements;

    return view('lists.list', compact('user', 'list', 'elements'));
}

In the UserLists model I have a elements relationship defined
public function elements(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(ListElements::class, 'list_id', 'id')
        ->orderByDesc('created_at');
}

I go through all the elements in a loop in the template and display them on the page
@foreach($elements as $element)
<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start mt-5">
    <div class="ms-2 me-auto">
        {{ $element->description }}
        @dump($element->images->image)
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="mb-1 text-end">
            <a href="{{ route('list.edit', ['user' => $user->id, 'list' => $list->id]) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
        </div>
        <div class="text-end">
            <form method="post" action="{{ route('list.delete', ['user' => $user->id, 'list' => $list->id]) }}">
                @csrf @method('DELETE')
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<hr>
@endforeach

Look, I'm doing a dump @dump($element->images->image). This is a relationship that is defined in the ListElements model
public function images(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(Image::class, 'list_element_id', 'id')->select(['image', 'thumbnail']);
}

when i do this dump i get an error Attempt to read property "image" on null

That means there's probably no images nevertheless you are still trying to get the image column value.
